How can I vent a two-hose AC into an exterior door opening?
I have a standard balcony door that opens inwards, sort of like this:

I want to install a two-hose portable AC and hook up the tubes to the outside. Short of going to a hardware store, getting a large piece of plywood and cutting two round holes in it, are there any pre-fabricated solutions I could use?
There are existing solutions for sliding doors and for windows but unfortunately the windows in the room are ~6 feet above the ground, so a regular hose won't be able to reach it.

Plexiglass, screening, placing the AC on a platform to reach the windows.  If you use the door, a platform/table would be more handy.

Extending the hoses to reach the windows would be safer to pets and children than putting the unit on a platform
